# Is the largest eigenvalue that matches an eigenvector that spans $v$ is independent of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators, change-of-basis

Let $W$ be a finate-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) and let $M: W\to W$ be a self-adjoint linear operator. Then there exists an orthonormal basis $B=\{\phi_i\}$ consisting of the eigenvectors of $M$. Denote the eigenvalues by $\lambda_i$ respectively. Let there be $v\in W$. Since $B$ is a basis of $W$, there exists a unique combination of $\alpha_i$ such that $v=\sum_i \alpha_i \phi_i$. Denote by
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_B(v) := \max_i\{\lvert\lambda_i\rvert
\mid \alpha_i\neq 0\}
\end{equation*}
the largest eigenvalue (in absolute value) that matches an eigenvector that spans $v$.
Equivalently, since $B$ is an orthogonal basis,
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_B(v) := \max_i\{\lvert\lambda_i\rvert \mid v\not\perp\phi_i \}.
\end{equation*}
where $v\not\perp\phi$ is defined as $\langle v, \phi \rangle \neq 0$.

Note that $B$ is not unique: there can be another orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $M$. My question is whether $\lambda_B(v)$ is independent of $B$. What is the simplest way to prove it? By simplest I mean easiest to understand for someone who has a math or CS degree.

Thank you!

Comment: The question is not research-level mathematics, so it should be on math.stackexchange, not here. (And the comment from Neal is wrong.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think it is research-level since it came to me during my research (I am currently writing my thesis for a Master's degree). Moreover, it involves a definition that is not taught during graduate-level. Yet, If people agree it should be moved to StackExchange, how should it be done? Can a moderator move it?

Comment: @Neal Thank you but I agree with Andreas that it's wrong. Can you prove what you said?

Comment: @AndreasBlass you're right, that's my mistake. I was thinking of a related concept and didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector space $W$ can be written as
$$
W=\bigoplus_i E_{\lambda_i},
$$
where $E_{\lambda_i}$ is the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Then if $\lambda_B(v)=\lambda$ for some basis $B$, it has the same value for any other basis as the the vector $\phi_\lambda$ associated to $\lambda$ cannot be written as a sum of the vectors in the other eigenspaces.

Notice that if the eigenvalues are all different, the orthonormal basis consisting of normalized eigenvectors of $M$ **is unique**, except for a reordering.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand how you reached the conclusion that "it has the same value for any other basis". We know that $\phi_\lambda$ can be written as a combination of other eigenvectors from its own eigenspace. So theoretically, with another basis, $\lambda_B(v)$ could be different.

Comment: @EllaShar, by definition all eigenvector in the eigenspace $E_\lambda$ have the same eigenvalue $\lambda$, then it doesn't matter how $\phi_\lambda$ is written, the important point is that it can only be written as sum of vectors **in** $E_\lambda$.

Comment: Oh you are correct, thank you!